# Ionic slides - show previous || next

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, slider

I'm using IONIC framework. 
I got a ng-repeat in the ion-slide-box. It works perfectly (I got like 10 slides generated in a dynamic way)

But I want some specific front: I wanna see  previous and next slides.

As you can see on my schemas.

[This is what I got now, on my screen I can see current slide but not previous and next one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GBYp.png)

[This is what I want, I can see previous and next slides on my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuP4U.png)

I've been trying to manage this with HTML + CSS, but it's not working. 
Any idea ?